# Entire page repeating with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I've ran an SQL query to obtain reviews relating to a specific film as part of a film review site.

I've managed to obtain the required results, however the entire top section of the webpage now duplicates in between every record.
I'm really not sure why this could be as I'm a complete beginner with PHP.

I assume it must be a simple syntax problem but I can't see it.
Any help would be great! Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
            try{
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx','xxx','xxx');
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
    $result = $conn->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM FILM F, GENRE G, REVIEW R, USER U 
    WHERE F.GENRE_ID = G.GENRE_ID 
    AND F.FILM_ID = R.FILM_ID
    AND U.USER_ID = R.USER_ID
    AND R.FILM_ID = 128
    ");
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()){
    ?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title><? echo $row['TITLE']; ?></title>
      <link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <meta name="description" content="A unique, ground-breaking website for all things relating to classical cinema. The Classic revolutionises the way that we see classic cinema, and provides the movie goer with an opportunity to find all the reviews they need!">
      <meta name="author" content="Stefan Batterbee">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="page">
         <header>
         <?php
         if(isset($_SESSION['Logged_In']))
{
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'You are logged in!<br>';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">
Click here to log out.</a>';
}
else
{   
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'You are not logged in!<br>';
    echo '<a href="log_in.php">Click here to log in,</a><br>';
    echo '<a href="register.php">or click here to register.</a>';
}
?>

</header>
         <nav>
            <ul id="navigation">
               <li><a href="index.php">H O M E </a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="genres(list).html">F I L M&nbsp; R E V I E W S </a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="articles(list).php">A R T I C L E S</a></li>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <li><a href="about_us.php">A B O U T &nbsp;U S</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div id="breadcrumbs">
            &nbsp; <a class="link" href="index.php">Home</a> > <a class="link" href="genres(list).php">Reviews</a> > <? echo '<a class="link" href="'.$row ['GENRE_TYPE'].'(list).php">'; echo $row ['GENRE_TYPE']; echo '</a>' ?> > <? echo '<a class="link" href="'.$row ['FILM_ID'].'.php">'; echo $row ['TITLE']; echo '</a>' ?>
         </div>
         <div id="filminfo">
            <img class="greyshadow" src="Images/2001aspaceodyssey.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="2001" longdesc="Images/2001aspaceodyssey.jpg">
            <div id="filminfotext">
               <h1><span itemprop="itemreviewed"><? echo $row['TITLE']; ?></span></h1>
               <br>
               <table width="500" height="80" border="0">
                  <tr>
                     <td>Genre:</td>
                     <td><? echo $row['GENRE_TYPE']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Release Year:</td>
                     <td><? echo $row['RELEASE_YEAR']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Starring:</td>
                     <td><? echo $row['LEAD_ACTOR']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Directed by:</td>
                     <td><? echo $row['DIRECTOR']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Running Time:</td>
                     <td><? echo $row['RUNNING_TIME']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="viewreviews">
            <h2>P R E V I O U S &nbsp; U S E R &nbsp; R E V I E W S</h2>
            <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">  
            <span itemprop="itemreviewed">2001: A Space Odyssey</span> - Classic Film Reviews
            <span itemprop="rating" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">      
            Rating: 
            <span itemprop="average">9.2</span> out of
            <span itemprop="best">10</span> 
            </span>
            based on
            <span itemprop="count">6</span> reviews.
            </span>
         </div>

      <div id="synopsis">   

   <?php
    echo '<table width="760" border="0">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td rowspan="2">';
    echo $row['RATING'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo '<td>'; 
    echo $row['USERNAME'];          
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'; echo $row['COMMENTS']; echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>'; 



    }
    $conn = null; ?>


         <center><a href="128post.php"><img src="Images/review_button.jpg"></a></center>
         </div>


         <footer>
            <p class="textleft">Created by Stefan Batterbee (2013)</p>
            <p class="textright">Click <a class="link" href="https://www.facebook.com/the.classic.cinema.reviews">HERE</a> to access our Facebook page.</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your page header, etc. is within a while loop - what are you expecting to happen? (Hint: Output the header of your page *first*, then start iterating though the database results.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a query that returns data from tables with different items count, this is influencing the results returned. To understand better, var_dump($row) and forget the html for now: you're getting:

TITLE - RELEASE_YEAR - GENRE_TYPE - RATING - USERNAME - COMMENT

all in the same row, repeated times the number of comments.  And you're using the single $row to output the whole page. Incidentally, should you have no reviews, you wouldn't even see the page once.

You should

1. remove the REVIEW table from the first query, and remove the while loop: this is a movie page, you only want to render the movie information once
2. run another query just before the table where you outupt the RATING (the one 760px wide), and query only the REVIEW table. Then run a while loop to print out all the ratings.
   Use different variable names ($ratingrow for example) so you don't lose your mind.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I'm that new to PHP I didn't actually know you could run two queries...

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your while loop before rendering the header. Move the PHP where you start the loop to the location where you want to start the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part of your code:

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()){
```

to:

```
$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

There is no reason to loop through the query results and this is the answer to your question of why it's *duplicates in between every record*.

Comment: This resulted in several error messages stating that the variables could not be located. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the variable's name that could not be located?

Comment: All of them, I received something similar to '
Notice: Undefined index: TITLE in /home/4199199/public_html/128rev.php on line 68' for every $row function.

Comment: Take a close look at the `$row` array and try using instead `$row[0]`, does it change anything to you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still the same problem.

Comment: @user3183576, could you please provide the full error message out?

Comment: I've managed to resolve it now. using 'while' but it works okay. Thank you for your support :)